# It is the best movie<,> I have watched before!

Tags: sentence-meaning

> 1. It is the best movie I have watched before!
> 2. It is the best movie, I have watched before!

I think there is a big difference between the 1 and the 2.
I suppose the difference would be that the 1 means the movie (I am watching now) is the best among the movies, which I have ever seen before, but different from the 1, the 2 means the movie is the best movie and I have watched the movie before once or several times.

Is my thinking correct?

( I know you guys would think that the 2 is absolutely odd because the movie cannot be the best in that I have never seen any other movies except that. That is to say how I estimate the movie is the best one not having seen any other movies. But the aim of this question is not for it but for the punctuation, so please overlook the odd point in meaning.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. I suspect you mean the much more idiomatic "It is the best movie I have ever watched."

Comment: The comma makes no difference to the meaning.  But both of them are very non-idiomatic and hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically incorrect, which is why you have the confusion.

Grammatically, you would say

> "It is the best movie I have ever watched"

and

> "It is the best movie, I have watched it before".

In these cases, there won't be any ambiguity.